# Will Blender 2.76 run smoothly on new PC?

Tags: workflow

I am considering finishing my old 2.76 files in Blender 2.76 so as to avoid any compatibility issues, before moving to Blender 3.1.  I am wondering, will Blender 2.76 run especially well on the PC recommended for Blender 3.1?

Windows 10
64-bit eight core CPU
32 GB RAM
2560×1440 display
Three button mouse or pen+tablet
Graphics card with 8 GB RAM

It would be excellent if it would run well on a powerful PC, because I need to get a new PC anyhow.  Or, will running this "old" version on a new computer cause glitches rather than improved performance? I'm currently working with much less RAM, so I am used to a lot of lag when animating even simple models.  If I could just see the models moving in real time, rather than lagging badly after a few seconds, that would be very helpful.  Thanks for any insights!

Comment: Try it and see? - You can have several Blender versions installed at the same time without them interfering with each other. I currently have 2.83, 2,93, 3,0.1 and 3.12 on this W10 machine and I doubt 2.79 would be any different. Just remember that you shouldn't load and then resave a file with a later version if you still want it to run on the earlier version that it was created on. It might work ok, but isn't guaranteed!

Comment: @JohnEason  I'll try that.  Thanks for the suggestion!